# How can I configure the perf counters in a Service Fabric Stateless service?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have looked at the options in the portal and also the resource group templates, but could not find a way to customize this list. 
Also, is it possible to add custom perf counters (assuming the code already creates them) for monitoring in the service fabric application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no integrated way to do this today, but there are three ways to do this:

1. Use Application Insights to monitor your application. There are some
   details of how to do this with Application Insights that are not Service
   Fabric specific [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-monitor-performance/#system-performance-counters). There is also a project on GitHub that shows
   how to integrate Azure Service Fabric with Application Insights.
2. Collect performance counters using Azure Diagnostics. Service Fabric is running on VMs, configuring diagnostics to collection from
       an Azure VM can be found [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-diagnostics/).
3. Use Operations Management Suite which can also collect standard and custom performance counters. See links in the post below (I'm not allowed to post more than 2 links)

Comment: OMS links are http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrmomgoescloud/archive/2015/10/18/send-scom-custom-performance-counters-to-oms.aspx and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt679065.aspx

Comment: Have to go with accepting this one as the answer, I managed to get it working with the DiagnosticsPlugin for service fabric.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this approach: [Setting up Application Insights for your Service Fabric application](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-diagnostics-application-insights-setup.md)

Comment: broken link , please re up